# how can two applications use single ASPState database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis

how can two or more applications use single ASPState database.

I had implemented SQL server session management. I have some asp.net applications deployed on my IIS where i want to implement SQL server session management, so i have ASPState DB, i want to share this DB for all applications.

DB- data base

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using the default ASPState database created by the supplied SQL scripts that come with .NET, the database is already designed for shared usage. Just configure each application to point to the same database. The session state is isolated in the db by using the application ID from IIS (i.e. /W3SVC/2165464565), so there's no collision of data.